# jQuery UI switchClass fails under IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, colors

I'm trying to use jQuery UI to animate a transition on a form and while the code **works correctly** in Firefox and Chrome, a Javascript error occures in IE8.

I'm using jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js and the error given is:

```
Message: 'end.0' is null or not an object - Line: 819 - Char: 6
```

My CSS:

```
.formfield {
    background-color: White;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
}

.formfieldselected {
    background-color: MintCream;
    border: none;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(":input").each(function()
    {
    var myInput = $(this);
    if (this.type == 'submit')
    {
        return;
    }
    myInput.bind('focusin', function()
    {
        $('#' + this.id + 'field').removeAttr('style'); // Reset Style if broken
        $('#' + this.id + 'field').switchClass('formfield', 'formfieldselected', 300);
        $('#' + this.id + 'helpbox').removeClass('helpboxhidden').addClass('helpboxvisible');
    });
    myInput.bind('focusout', function()
    {
        $('#' + this.id + 'field').switchClass('formfieldselected', 'formfield', 300);
        $('#' + this.id + 'helpbox').removeClass('helpboxvisible').addClass('helpboxhidden');
    });
    });
...
}
```

And finally one of the elements this code is supposed to be working on:

```
<DIV id="eventnamefield" class="formfield">
    <DIV id="eventnamehelpbox" class="helpboxhidden">
    This name is used throughout the system to refer to this event and is shown to Attendees
    </DIV>
    <label for="eventname" class="adminformlabel">Event Name:</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="eventname" value="" id="eventname" maxlength="50" class="adminforminput"  />
</DIV>
```

Comment: Sorry about the bogus answer I deleted. I misunderstood your code completely :-)  However I can suggest that you open up the IE8 "Developer tools" and let the debugger show you more about the error.

Comment: @Pointy All that tells me is that the error is somewhere in jQuery UI its self. and that b.end is indeed set to Undefined. Also, that I think it takes place maybe during some attempt to change the object's size maybe.

Comment: Ah, well it's a pain when that happens. Perhaps however you can look up the stack trace and find something in your code. The jQuery libraries aren't super-careful about handling errors like that, I suspect for performance reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer.

Turns out jQuery UI under IE can not handle colours referenced by name. Changing the colours to their hex codes in the CSS fixed the problem.

Comment: As an addition, if you don't supply any color at all to the background and leave it the default white, this problem also occurs.  I was having the same issue when I defined no background-color (not even a color referenced by name) but when I added the #FFF white color as the default background-color for all necessary elements it solved this issue for me.